# loading Json data from server using AIR for android and flashpro

Tags: android, json, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm trying to load json data from a service, the application is created in flash professional cs6 using AIR for android, yet  every time I connect to the service I get a server status response of 500 hat's it, here's the code:

```
    import flash.net.URLVariables;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.HTTPStatusEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;


   var reqst:URLRequest = new URLRequest();

    function contactServer():void{

    var urlVar:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    //  

    reqst = new URLRequest("http://xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx.asmx?op=Login");


    urlVar.UserName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    urlVar.Password = "xxxxxxxxxxx";



    reqst.requestHeaders=[new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")];

    reqst.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    reqst.data = urlVar;


    var my_loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    my_loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;

    my_loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler_);
    my_loader.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler);
    my_loader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
    my_loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
    my_loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
    my_loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);



    try{
        my_loader.load(reqst);
    }catch(error:Error){
        throw new Error(" we have and error " + error, 100);
        debug_.text = "predicted error: " + error;
    }

    }

    function completeHandler_(event:Event):void{
    var serverResult:String = String(event.target.data);

    debug_.text += event.toString();
   }

   function openHandler(event:Event):void {

    debug_.text +=  "\n" + event.toString();
   }

   function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
    trace("progressHandler loaded:" + event.bytesLoaded + " total: " + event.bytesTotal);
   }


   function httpStatusHandler(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void {
    trace("httpStatusHandler: " + event);

    debug_.text += "\n" + event.toString();
   }

   function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void { 
    trace("securityErrorHandler: " + event);
    throw new Error("securityErrorHandler: " + event, 1);

    debug_.text += "\n" + event.toString();
  }


   function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
    trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
    throw new Error("ioErrorHandler: " + event, 2);

    debug_.text += "\n" +event.toString();
   }


    contactServer();
```

I'm really clueless here, any help appreciated.

Comment: You probably should log requests server-side and see if your app behaves correctly. Error 500 is not something that a client could fix, but error 400 is. Your app is probably receiving invalid values and does not have a code to return a detailed error on such mistakes.

Comment: i think ur right @Vesper , tried the same code on a different web method , only this time it takes it's parameters using GET method and worked fine , tested on android device and returned the json set